# RStudio tfestimator does not work with distribute strategy from tensorflow

Tags: r, tensorflow, rstudio, reticulate

I'm having trouble with Rstudio's tfestimator package to work with Tensorflow Estimators... it does not appear to work with any of the DistributionStrategy that Google provides for automatic scaling of estimators to multiple GPUs. It errors out with a "C stack usage XXXX is too close to the limit".

Minimum reproduce-able example (converted to R from: [ https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/README.md ] )

```
library("tensorflow")
library("tfestimators")

model_fn <- function(features, labels, mode, params, config)
{
  layer   <- tf$layers$Dense(1L)
  logits  <- layer(features)

  if(mode == tf$estimator$ModeKeys$PREDICT) 
  {
    predictions = dict("logits", logits)
  }

  loss = tf$losses$mean_squared_error(labels = labels, predictions = tf$reshape(logits, list()))

  if(mode == tf$estimator$ModeKeys$EVAL)
  {
    return(estimator_spec(mode = mode, loss = loss))
  }

 if(mode == tf$estimator$ModeKey$TRAIN)
 {
    train_op = tf$train$GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2)$minimize(loss)
 }

 return(estimator_spec(mode = model, loss= loss, train_op = train_op))
}  


input_fn <- function()
{
  features <- tf$data$Dataset$from_tensors(list(list(1.0)))$'repeat'(100L)
  labels = tf$data$Dataset$from_tensors(1.0)$'repeat'(100L)

  return(tf$data$Dataset$zip(tuple(features, labels)))
}

## MAIN PROGRAM LOOP ##

distribution = tf$contrib$distribute$MirroredStrategy()
config = tf$estimator$RunConfig(train_distribute = distribution)

classifier <- estimator(model_fn, config = config)

train(classifier, input_fn)
evaluate(classifier, input_fn)
```

Error returned:

```
2018-11-18 13:56:02.190515: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-11-18 13:56:02.448221: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-11-18 13:56:02.609134: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:0c:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-11-18 13:56:02.610086: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2018-11-18 13:56:03.325110: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-11-18 13:56:03.325159: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 1 
2018-11-18 13:56:03.325169: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N Y 
2018-11-18 13:56:03.325174: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 1:   Y N 
2018-11-18 13:56:03.325779: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10409 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-11-18 13:56:03.326896: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10409 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0c:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-11-18 13:56:03.415536: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2018-11-18 13:56:03.415606: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-11-18 13:56:03.415617: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 1 
2018-11-18 13:56:03.415623: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N Y 
2018-11-18 13:56:03.415628: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 1:   Y N 
2018-11-18 13:56:03.416166: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 10409 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-11-18 13:56:03.416376: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:1 with 10409 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0c:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Error: C stack usage  898515125908 is too close to the limit
```

Comment: I think you need to limit the amount of GPU memory you are using with the single session if this is possible at all.

Comment: I'll take a look at it and get back to you.  There is an option to set a fractional limit on the % of total GPU memory used.  Just not clear why this simple model won't fit in 11 GB of GPU space (it works fine without the .MirroredStrategy option.